# rails not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run the gem command to install rails on my macbook pro early 2011, it seems to install it, but then when I run any rails command the terminal gives me an error saying that rails is not currently installed on the system any help please?

The command I'm using to install rails is:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Then the terminal outputs:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.2.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.8...
```

Then I execute a command like:

```
rails --version
```

And the following error shows up on the terminal:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: Try "sudo rails --version" (without the quotes) and see what that gives you. It is possible that since you tried to use the command without "sudo" it is attempting to access a different directory structure in which rails is not actually present, since you had to install it with it.

Comment: Luis is right, and it would be preferable to install without using `sudo`. (This caused me a good deal of pain when I was getting started with Ruby/Rails...in my case, using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) for a per-user installation helped.)

Answer (score 1):

> Mac OS X users can use Rails One Click.

http://railsoneclick.com/ 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html